# Custom ListView filter/search for SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, search

I'm using this tutorial [enter link description here](https://androidjson.com/android-add-search-box-filter-sqlite/) to search custom ListView for SQLite.
But my search doesn't work.
I did everything as shown and copied some of the codes.

What am I doing wrong?

This tutorial is for using an Activity, I'm using it in a Fragment.

Could it be beacuse of that?

My CustomAdapter

```
public class UrunAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Urun>{
private Context c;
private ArrayList<Urun> originalList;
private ArrayList<Urun> filteredList;
private UrunAdapter.SubjectDataFilter myFilter;


public UrunAdapter(@NonNull Context context,int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Urun> urun) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.c=context;
    this.originalList=new ArrayList<>();
    this.originalList.addAll(urun);
    this.filteredList=new ArrayList<>();
    this.filteredList.addAll(urun);

}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.satir3,parent,false);


    TextView tv1=v.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
    TextView tv2=v.findViewById(R.id.textView27);
    TextView tv3=v.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
    TextView tv4=v.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
    TextView tv5=v.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
    Urun provider= this.getItem(position);
    if (provider != null) {

        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(provider.getId()));
        tv2.setText(provider.getBarkodNo());
        tv3.setText(provider.getAdi());
        tv4.setText(String.valueOf(provider.getAlis()));
        tv5.setText(String.valueOf(provider.getSatis()));
        tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return v;
}

public  void guncelle(){UrunAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();}

public class SubjectDataFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

        charSequence = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        if (charSequence.toString().length() > 0) {

            ArrayList<Urun> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++) {
                Urun subject = originalList.get(i);

                if (subject.toString().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence))

                    arrayList1.add(subject);
            }
            filterResults.count = arrayList1.size();

            filterResults.values = arrayList1;
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                filterResults.values = originalList;

                filterResults.count = originalList.size();
            }
        }
        return filterResults;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

        filteredList = (ArrayList<Urun>) filterResults.values;
        clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (int i = 0, l = filteredList.size(); i < l; i++)
            add(filteredList.get(i));

        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }


}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if (myFilter == null) {

        myFilter = new UrunAdapter.SubjectDataFilter();
    }
    return myFilter;
}
```

My Pojo

```
public class Urun  {
int id;
String barkodNo,adi;
double alis,satis;

public Urun(){

}

public Urun(int id, String barkodNo, String adi, double alis, double satis) {
    this.id = id;
    this.barkodNo = barkodNo;
    this.adi = adi;
    this.alis = alis;
    this.satis = satis;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBarkodNo() {
    return barkodNo;
}

public void setBarkodNo(String barkodNo) {
    this.barkodNo = barkodNo;
}

public String getAdi() {
    return adi;
}

public void setAdi(String adi) {
    this.adi = adi;
}

public double getAlis() {
    return alis;
}

public void setAlis(double alis) {
    this.alis = alis;
}

public double getSatis() {
    return satis;
}

public void setSatis(double satis) {
    this.satis = satis;
}
```

UrunListesi.fragment

```
public class UrunListesi extends Fragment implements Tanimla {
ListView liste;
View v;
Helper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
UrunAdapter adapter;
Cursor c;
int id;
String barkod,adi;
double alis,satis;
Urun bilgi;
TextView t0;
String s0;
EditText barkodaGore,adaGore;
ArrayList<Urun> list;

public UrunListesi() {

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diger, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    init();
    //listeYukle();
}

private void listeYukle() {

    helper = new Helper(getActivity());
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "Select * from tblUrunler";
    c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id_urunler"));
        barkod=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("urun_barkodNo"));
        adi=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("urun_adi"));
        alis=c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("urun_alis"));
        satis=c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("urun_satis"));

        bilgi = new Urun();

        bilgi.setId(id);
        bilgi.setBarkodNo(barkod);
        bilgi.setAdi(adi);
        bilgi.setAlis(alis);
        bilgi.setSatis(satis);

        list.add(bilgi);
        adapter.add(bilgi);
    }
    liste.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void init() {

    liste=v.findViewById(R.id.liste);
    list=new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new UrunAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.satir3,list);
    barkodaGore=v.findViewById(R.id.barkodaGore);
    adaGore=v.findViewById(R.id.adaGore);
    liste.isTextFilterEnabled();


    barkodaGore.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(barkodaGore.getText().toString());
                adapter.guncelle();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    adaGore.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            adapter.guncelle();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    liste.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            t0=view.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
            s0=t0.getText().toString();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
            } else {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            }
            builder.setTitle("Ne Yapmak istersiniz?")
                    .setMessage("Seçiniz")
                    .setPositiveButton("Sil", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            sil();
                            adapter.clear();
                            listeYukle();
                            adapter.guncelle();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Silme", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void sil() {
    helper=new Helper(getActivity());
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("tblUrunler","id_urunler="+Integer.parseInt(s0),null);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    listeYukle();
}
```

Comment: wrong tutorial: instead of `ArrayAdapter` use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and for searching purposes setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: do you have any tutorial for this?

Comment: no i dont have, just read the official documentation, not those muddling tutorials

Comment: ok.thanks. i will try simple cursor adapter

Comment: what does uri mean in simple cursor adapter?

Comment: Uri? what Uri? Where did you see it?

Comment: Cursor cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver.query(uri,...)